# How can I access ejabberd REST API from server side

Tags: server-side, ejabberd

I am new to eJabberd, after setting up the server and be able to send messages between users I want to be able to create rooms from our backend server (not from our clients).

I read this article:
https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/oauth/

But I did not understand how can I use the api from our server side (for example, to automatically create rooms for our users), how can I obtain a token for the server to use the API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using **mod_rest** - http interface to post data to ejabberd. You can read more about configuration & examples [here](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/tree/master/mod_rest).

Do consider adding some restrictions so that only your server can use the http interface.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added mod_rest to the .yaml file and I see the server is listening (using netstat). I am still dont understand how can I send the api call. I want to create a room so I want to use "POST /api/create_room", but using the module I need to post to http://server:5285/rest what am I missing here?

Comment: I also tried to POST like in the example, with a body of "<message to="test1@localhost" from="localhost/rest"><body>World</body></message>"  I am getting 500 for that.

Comment: getting crash now <0.478.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.478.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: call to undefined function acl:parse_ip_netmask({127,0,0,1})

Comment: OK after fighting with this for hours I will just use the ejabberedctr to create rooms and use the api, probably will install django or something to control it.

Comment: @adiohaion Yes, u need to have some backend system that will make a post http request to the ejabberd server with the data to create room.